# How to solve hidden text , on scrolling Footer that hides text of body in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple App with Sticky header and footer , however when I scroll down the Footer hides the content of the body.

The code is here :

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-goldwasser-b8u1p

Here is the footer :

```
import React from 'react';
import './Footer.css';

const Footer = () => (
  <div className="footer">
    <p>This is some content in sticky footer</p>
  </div>
);

export default Footer;
```

And its style :

```
.footer {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 195, 64);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Any idea what might cause this ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-fermi-c2p7d?file=/src/App.js:0-27, all other files are blank

Comment: @VivekDoshi : Fixed , thanks : https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-goldwasser-b8u1p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's due to :

```
.footer {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(235, 195, 64);
  position: fixed; // <----- HERE
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

It will overlap.

**Solution** to this apply some bottom padding or margin same or grater then footer's height.

```
// someRandomText.js
<div style={{padding: '80px 40px 92px 40px'}}> //<--- Made some change here
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-resonance-p276h?file=/src/SomeRandomText.js)**